# Deleteing lists in C++ causes crash

Tags: c++, list, crash

What is the correct way to delete the contents of a list. currently I am doing this.

```
std::list<CSchSuggestBar*>::const_iterator iter = m_pRescheduleReasons.begin();
for (; iter != m_pRescheduleReasons.end(); ++iter)
{
    delete *iter;
}
```

however the delete *iter seems to cause a crash.

Is it preferred if i just call `m_pRescheduleReasons.clear()`

edit:

The way How the pointers are stored in the list as as follows: (I did a separate project to isolate the issue: when delete is called the first time the crash appears.. however there is a valid object in which the pointer is pointing too? So im not too sure why it would crash?

```
std::vector<Foo*> f;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  f.push_back(f1);
}
 std::vector<Foo*>::const_iterator it = f.begin();
for (; it != f.end(); ++it)
{
   delete *it; 
}
```

EDIT: i solved this was a stupid error on my behalf

Comment: What do the pointers in the list actually point at? How do you add items to the list? *What* do you add to the list?

Comment: I found so many good suggestion from googling "deleting list in c++"

Comment: Also note that the `clear` function will just make the list empty, it will not delete the pointers inside the list so if you truly have allocated those pointers then you will have memory leaks. However, you should probably clear the list after you have deleted all pointers in it.

Comment: Do you have a good reason for not using `std::list<CSchSuggestBar>`? If so, it may be worth mentioning it in the question.

Comment: I think your problem has nothing to do with `std::list` (look at the simple working example in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28107465/2932052)), so you'll have the same issue when switching to `std::vector`. That's why I voted down, I hope you can fix this.

Comment: As the other comment suggested, your problem has nothing to do with std::list.  You would probably have the same problem if you stored these pointers in a plain-old array.  The issue is that you're calling `delete` on pointers that we have no idea how they are initialized or manipulated.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  i have updated showing how the pointers in the list are initializd.

Comment: @ShamariCampbell This wouldn't compile: `f.push_back(f1);` what are you really pushing back?

Comment: `EDIT: i solved this was a stupid error on my behalf` - at least tell us which one. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
std::list<std::unique_ptr<SomeType>> mylist;
```

when it will automatically delete its contents with `list::clear()` or `list::~list()`. Since `unique_ptr` cannot be copied, you must move them

```
mylist.push_back(std::move(std::unique_ptr<SomeType>(new SomeType(args))));
mylist.push_back(std::move(make_unique(new SomeType(args))); // C++14
```

You could also use `list::emplace` as in

```
mylist.emplace_back(new SomeType(args));
```

but if the node allocation fails, the memory allocated by `new SomeType(args)` will not be assigned to a `unique_ptr` and hence leak.

Comment: +1 for suggesting `unique_ptr`. -1 for suggesting `emplace_back` for a container containing `unique_ptr`. If the allocation of the list node fails, the pointer will most likely leak.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` is the right choice in *most cases*. But I think this doesn't address the actual problem. If the asker applies this suggestion, the problem will probably get even bigger. This consideration made my vote down.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Good point. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @Wolf I answered the (original) question, even though my suggestion may not solve the actual problem (which was ill-addressed by the question), but why should the problem get bigger? Your downvote suggest that using `unique_ptr` is unhelpful, which I contest.

Comment: You are right, the question is low quality (also after my edit). The suggestion to switch to `unique_ptr` is really a good advice. Why it's  getting worse is that the crash cause would be hidden. For example a closing scope may causes it, which is harder to debug. I think the asker has only basic C++ skills.

Comment: @Wolf The problem may be harder to diagnose, but that's not the same as the problem gets bigger, i.e. harder to solve once diagnosed.

Comment: You mean the problem of resource management. The *actual problem* in the question was a *crashing destructor*.

Answer (score 0):

Old thing, i think you want something like deleteAll macro in Qt.

```
   bool deleteCSchSuggestBar(CSchSuggestBar *item)
   {
      delete item;
      return true;
   }

   m_pRescheduleReasons.remove_if(deleteCSchSuggestBar);
   m_pRescheduleReasons.clear();
```

Comment: you could use a lambda in `remove_if`.

Comment: of course, but i am usually aiming for old versions of c++, not C++11.

Comment: Why are you restricting to old C++? How old? 1998? pre-standard?

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted

```
std::list<CSchSuggestBar*>::const_iterator iter = m_pRescheduleReasons.begin();
for (; iter != m_pRescheduleReasons.end(); ++iter)
{
    delete *iter;
}
```

works fine. I made a [working example](http://ideone.com/ff9hw8) from it.

The crash may be caused by the destructor call itself.

Or, which is more likely in your case: you are calling `delete` on a **dangling pointer** (the address of a former object that was already destroyed). Try to add this line after destroying all objects in the loop:

```
m_pRescheduleReasons.clear();
```

This results in an empty list.

Answer (score -1):

**Is it preferred if i just call m_pRescheduleReasons.clear()**

It really comes down to the use case...

if you use the delete iter; call, just the iterators will be invalidated....But If you want to delete the pointee too, then ,delete *iter should do it.

Consider this:

IF you own the objects in that list, then, deleting those objects would be a valid use case.

But say in a use case scenario such as Subject-observer pattern, where you need to maintain a list of observers, randomly deleting the observers would not really be a good design choice.

Comment: The asker stated that `delete *iter seems to cause a crash` I think this is really the case, but the "malicious" destructor itself is not included in the post. BTW: the asker doesn't use `delete iter`, I think this answer isn't helpful so far (-1)

Comment: This response was to the question Is it preferred if i just call m_pRescheduleReasons.clear()?? I donot understand how this deserves a vote down....The use case is legit, isnt it?